# Reading files into array python

Tags: python, arrays

I have multiple files with thousands of rows that I need to compare.
for example I want to do subtraction  `file3 = file2 - file1`,

```
file1  
1 10 5  
2 20 4  
3 30 3



file2  
5 20 10  
6 30 10  
7 40 10
```

`file3` would be

```
4 10 5  
4 10 6  
4 10 7
```

I wonder what is the best way to do this type of calculations. I am trying Python, but I am having a hard time to read the file to python to make it the proper kind of array for calculation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.genfromtxt('file1')
a2 = np.genfromtxt('file2')
a3 = a2 - a1
print(a3)
array([[  4.,  10.,   5.],
       [  4.,  10.,   6.],
       [  4.,  10.,   7.]])
```

Then you could save that array with [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) with format `%d` if you need output as integers:

```
np.savetxt('file3', a3, fmt='%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Open both files, then loop through them with `zip`:

```
with open('file1.txt') as first, open('file2.txt') as second, open('file3.txt', 'w') as output:
    for a, b in zip(first, second):
        a = map(int, a.split())
        b = map(int, b.split())
        output.write(' '.join(map(str, (y-x for x,y in zip(a,b)))) + '\n')
```